# React Typescript object literal error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that simply renders a row of data and has a delete button for each row.  Clicking delete should simply change the state using a filter to filter out the clicked row.  Why do I get the error below.

I tried debugging use the console.log and I am indeed getting the correct row.id and rowId to filter on, but my rows state is not being reassigned.

```
interface TableSampleProps {
    rows: any[];
}

interface TableSampleState {
    rows: any[];
}

export class TableSample extends React.Component<TableSampleProps, TableSampleState> {
    constructor(props: TableSampleProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           rows: this.props.rows.concat(),
        };
    }

    public render() {
        return <MyTable rows={this.state.rows} onDeleteRow={this.deleteRow} />;
    }

    private deleteRow = (rowId: number) => {
        // console.log(rowId);
        // this.state.rows.filter((row) => console.log(row.id !== rowId));
        this.setState = {
            rows: this.state.rows.filter((row) => row.id !== rowId),
         };
    }
}
```

> ] ERROR in ./src/ts/components/table-sample-tool.tsx [0] (57,13): error TS2322:
>   Type '{ rows: any[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ (f: (prevState: TableSample State, props: TableSampleProps) =>
>   Pick, ...'. [0]   Object literal may only specify
>   known properties, and 'rows' does not exist in type '{ (f: (prevS tate: TableSampleState, props: TableSampleProps) =>
>   Pick, ...'. [0] Child html-webpack-plugin for
>   "index.html": [0]     chunk    {0} index.html 542 kB [entry] [0]
>   + 4 hidden modules [0] webpack: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setState({rows=...` instead of `setState = {rows...`. You can do `this.state = {}` in the constructor but `setState` is a function.

Comment: Duh!! Totally overlooked that cause I copied from the constructor. Thanks!

Comment: 1: Your code is invalid syntax 2: `setState` is asynchronous. Accessing previous state via `this.state` inside it does not guarantee you get the previous state @user1991118

Answer (score 0):

That is now how you set state! `setState` is a *function*, you don't assign it (hence the error), you *call it*, passing in an object indicating updated properties in state:

```
this.setState({
    rows: this.state.rows.filter((row) => row.id !== rowId),
});
```

Another thing to note is that `setState` is asynchronous so accessing `this.state.rows` inside it will not guarantee the previous state. Use a callback for `setState`, the first argument to the callback will be the previous state, and return an object from the callback like so:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    rows: prevState.rows.filter((row) => row.id !== rowId),
}));
```

This will guarantee that you're accessing previous state.